# I am trying to put info from a crawler into a json file but i get the json multiple top level error when i add a new object, how can i solve this?

Tags: python, json

```
def write_json(name, details, price, filename="Autovit_json.json"):
   auto_dict = {"Daily Offer": {"Name": name,
                                 "Details": details,
                                 "Price": price
                                 }
                }

   with open(filename, 'a') as json_file:
       json.dump(auto_dict, json_file)
       json_file.write('\n')
```

name, details and price changes daily from the site i used the crawler

Comment: Dont put multiple top elements into the json. Use different files. Or add your first result as "List" of that result into the json, then on later additions, read the json, convert to objects, add new result, convert to json and store again.

Comment: Can you show me on the code i gave because i'm kind of new to json( also it needs to be in a list not different files)